# Java Play Framework: "No java installations was detected."

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I've inherited and am maintaining a scala/play app that was built several years ago (2014).  Every night there's a cron job executing a shell script to restart the app.  Running this script from the command line at any time works just fine as well.  The app stops, cleans up, rebuilds then restarts.

I've been asked to build a php page which will allow this same shell script to be run via php.  I thought it would be very straightforward, but when I exec() the same shell script, I get the output message, ""No java installations was detected."

But of course it is there, where the variables say it should be.

I've tried cd'ing into the directory first before executing the script, and I've tried executing the script as the owner/user of the cpanel account (which is generally how the script is run from the command line).  Always the same message.  I temporarily tried adding the user to the wheel group (terrible idea long-term I know), but even that didn't work.

I thought it must be some sort of cpanel or server issue, and reached out to the host of the VPS but they didn't think so.  The developer of the app is no longer reachable.  My guess is it's something he could fix in 5 minutes, I just have no familiarity with this framework.

I've reviewed everything I can online several times and just don't see anything relevant...

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is it restarted every night?

Comment: Good question - honestly I don't know.  The developer wrote that shell script and implemented the cron job.  Perhaps it grows unstable or slower with time?

Comment: do you have java installed on the php server?

Comment: It's the same server, and the same account in cpanel, but the php script and the java app are in a separate subdomain as far as the web server is concerned.  Perhaps this is the issue then?  But php doesn't directly execute the java app, the shell script does.